# Android Generally Just Breaks

Tags: android

I have been playing around with an android application and just restarted to code it again, to see what I can remember off the top of my head. The problem is, I have completely broken the application and don't understand why.

The application will load for a little bit, and display some form of layout (which aren't any of the defined ones) and then crash.

Here are some bits of code, let me know if you need to see anything else:

The manifest:

```
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity android:name="org.mjth.online_sn.main" android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name="org.mjth.online_sn.live" android:label="@string/app_name"></activity>
        <activity android:name="org.mjth.online_sn.login_form" android:label="@string/app_name"></activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Main.java

```
import java.util.EmptyStackException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;

//Will do the default setup and checks
public class main extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //Locks screen orientation to portrait for now
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

        //Checks to see if we have valid authorisation keys and files
        SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("org.mjth.online_sn", MODE_PRIVATE);

        try{

            if(pref.getString("auth_id", "").equals("") == false){
                throw new EmptyStackException();
            }

            if(pref.getString("auth_pass", "").equals("") == false){
                throw new EmptyStackException();
            }

            if(pref.getString("lcl_first_name", "").equals("") == false){
                throw new EmptyStackException();
            }

            if(pref.getString("lcl_last_name", "").equals("") == false){
                throw new EmptyStackException();
            }

            if(pref.getString("lcl_expiry", "").equals("") == false){
                throw new EmptyStackException();
            }

            //TODO: Check if expiry is past todays date.

            //We passed all local checks, set view to live and double check on background
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), live.class);
            startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
        }catch (EmptyStackException e){
            //No valid credentials were found.
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), login_form.class);
            startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
        }


    }



}
```

login_form.java

```
import org.mjth.online_sn.R;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class login_form extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.login_form);
    }
}
```

live.java

```
import org.mjth.online_sn.R;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class live extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.live);
    }
}
```

**Update:** When disabling the action intent code I get the following error:

```
12-12 22:58:49.653: E/AndroidRuntime(1930): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{org.mjth.online_sn/org.mjth.online_sn.main}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.mjth.online_sn.main
12-12 22:58:49.653: E/AndroidRuntime(1930):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2024)
12-12 22:58:49.653: E/AndroidRuntime(1930):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2125)
12-12 22:58:49.653: E/AndroidRuntime(1930):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:140)
12-12 22:58:49.653: E/AndroidRuntime(1930):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1227)
12-12 22:58:49.653: E/AndroidRuntime(1930):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-12 22:58:49.653: E/AndroidRuntime(1930):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-12 22:58:49.653: E/AndroidRuntime(1930):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
12-12 22:58:49.653: E/AndroidRuntime(1930):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-12 22:58:49.653: E/AndroidRuntime(1930):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-12 22:58:49.653: E/AndroidRuntime(1930):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
12-12 22:58:49.653: E/AndroidRuntime(1930):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
12-12 22:58:49.653: E/AndroidRuntime(1930):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-12 22:58:49.653: E/AndroidRuntime(1930): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.mjth.online_sn.main
12-12 22:58:49.653: E/AndroidRuntime(1930):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
12-12 22:58:49.653: E/AndroidRuntime(1930):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
12-12 22:58:49.653: E/AndroidRuntime(1930):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
12-12 22:58:49.653: E/AndroidRuntime(1930):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1057)
12-12 22:58:49.653: E/AndroidRuntime(1930):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2015)
12-12 22:58:49.653: E/AndroidRuntime(1930):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: Please post logcat output. And isn't there any setContentView() call in your Main.java?

Comment: That's the thing, there is no error code where it breaks in LogCat or Console. And the main class is just a class to check a few things and initiate the next activity (which has the UI linked).. I don't need to link the main class to a UI do I?

Comment: I am not sure about that. But as its an activity, I assume setContentView() should be called. Not sure. Sorry

Comment: Its Not necessary to call ` setContentView()` .

Comment: Try to clean and rebuild your application. Looks like `import org.mjth.online_sn.R;` is the problem. Rebuild will remove that and may be your problem will be solved.

Comment: Without that import, I get the error that R can't be resolved to a variable.

Comment: I just disabled the intent part which swaps to the other action and finally got an error code in LogCat. I posted it above